# hello i need to create a auto increment invoice number

Tags: python, django

I need to create an auto increasing invoice number starting from 000001 and going up ex.000001, 000002, 000003 and so on
right now i have this code that i took from another stack overflow question but i dont want the MAG part

```
    def increment_invoice_number(self):
    last_invoice = Transaction.objects.all().order_by('id').last()
    if not last_invoice:
        return 'MAG0001'
    invoice_no = last_invoice.invoice_no
    invoice_int = int(invoice_no.split('MAG')[-1])
    new_invoice_int = invoice_int + 1
    new_invoice_no = 'MAG' + str(new_invoice_int)
    return new_invoice_no

invoice_no = models.CharField(max_length=500, default=increment_invoice_number, null=True, blank=True)
```

i want my invoice num to start with 000001

Comment: Why is `invoice_no` a `CharField` here if it contains only a number?

Comment: do i change it to a decimalField?

Comment: no, to an `IntegerField` in case it is an integral number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an `IntegerField` instead of a `CharField` for the invoices:

```
from django.db.models import Max

def invoice_number():
    invid = Invoice.objects.aggregate(
        max_inv=Max('invoice_no')
    )['max_inv']
    if invid is not None:
        return invid + 1
    return 0

class Invoice(models.Model):
    invoice_no = models.IntegerField(default=invoice_number, unique=True, editable=False)
```

We thus determine the maximum value for `invoice_no`, and then assign this as default value for the `invoice_no` of our `Invoice` model.

`unique=True` will prevent having two (or more) invoices with the same `invoice_no`. If there is a *race condition*, then one of the two views will error on this. You thus can implement a retry mechanism to eventually assign a valid invoice number.

By making it `editable=False`, this will *not* appear in the `ModelForm`s and `ModelAdmin`s for the `Invoice` model. You can omit this if the form should make the field editable.